# CSS - WebKit table-cell display 100% lacks 1 pixel of width?

Tags: css, width, css-tables

I have an image overlay that has width of 100%, the overlay is being displayed as `table-cell`, unfortunately the 100% width seems to be 100% minus 1 pixel for all WebKit browsers. Any idea why is that happening and how to fix it?

Here's the HTML:

```
  <ul class="portfolio">
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
  </ul>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
  background: #222;
}

.portfolio li {
  display: inline-block; 
  background: #fff;
  width: 19%;
  margin: 1% 2%;
  height: 100px;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green url('http://cool-iphonewallpapers.com/download/green-background.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
}

.overlay {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.overlay:hover {
  background: #000;
}

.button {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And exemplary code, looks fine in Firefox & IE and buggy in Chrome / Opera (laster versions using Blink). Notice the 1 pixel gap on the right side of each .overlay:

http://jsbin.com/afAmIhO/1/

Comment: I think this is a bug in the Chromium project. I can't replicate this on Safari 7.0 (9537.71) on my Mac. Maybe you should submit a bug to the [Chromium project](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: As stated by Tyler Eich there is a bug in Chromium.  Try changing the class overlay to a width: 100.9%.

Comment: Okay, thanks, any idea how long might it take them to fix it? Is tis 100.9% width trick safe (won't it cause mess in older browsers)? @SpencerLeonard, answer this question with 100.9% idea so I'd be able to accept is as an answer.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a fix in the immediate pipeline.  I do know that the Chrome Dev Team is aware and looking into the issue.  That is the best I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an acceptable hack for your case:

HTML:

```
  <ul class="portfolio">
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div> </div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><div class="image"><div class="overlay"><div class="button">+</div></div></div></a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #222;
}
.portfolio li {
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #fff;
    width: 19%;
    margin: 1% 2%;
    height: 100px;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green url('http://cool-iphonewallpapers.com/download/green-background.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
}
.overlay {
    display: table;
    width: 100.9%;  /*Hack */
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

.overlay:hover {
        background: #000;
    }
    .button {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }